# Determine (detect, recognize) visitors Facebook language

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, cookies

After couple months of researching without results I make decision to make this post. I would like to ask you if there are any possibility to determine visitors language which are using into Facebook.
For example:

Visitor X comes to my website from Facebook or any other referral, how can I know which language they are using into Facebook.

Comment: your best options is to use GEO_IP information of your visitor's IP address. You can implement a service similar to ifconfig.co on your backend and match countries to languages.

Comment: If your users are using Facebook to login to your site, you could probably get it from their profile that way. Otherwise, I doubt it's possible.

Comment: If users authenticate with a fb app on your page, you can access their public profile information, which includes their language and locale.

Comment: Thank you all for answering :) I will try that soultions with fb users authenticate ...